# Azure Function Trigger from Event Hub in another account

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am working with multiple Azure accounts, for example account A is my account, and B is another separate account.

In the other account (B), logs are being sent into Azure Event Hub, and i have access the primary/secondary keys etc. to access.

What I want to do is have that Event Hub (B) trigger a Azure function in my account (A) to do some processing on those logs.  Is it possible to have an Event Hub from another account trigger a function from another account?  Right now when i look at the connections possible, i can only see my personal namespace(s), IOT Hub, and Custom.  Is there a key/value pair i should be generating from the other account (B) so i can access via the "custom" connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Function created using your Azure subscription A can create a trigger that is listening on the Event Hub created using Azure subscription B. All you have to do is provide the correct and valid connection string from the Event Hub created using subscription B.